# Spacing issues in image captioning while using moderncv

Tags: graphics, captions, minipage, moderncv, includegraphics

I'm using moderncv and I want to add a caption to an inserted graphic. I'm currently using this code

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{MLPipeRS.png} \\
  Figure 1: heading of figure.
\end{minipage}
```

However, I see big space between figure and caption. How can I remove this spacing?
[image]

I tried with

```
\includegraphics[scale=.8]{MLPipeRS.png} \\Fig. 1. Conceptual architecture of imbalanced classification using DL models.
```

It didn't work as well!

I want the above figure as below:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Does the image itself have large whitespace boundaries, or is it properly cropped? There are ways to virtually crop it with includegraphics, but in my mind cropping it with an external image editor (or right at the source) would be preferable.

Comment: U r right! I fixed it already!